# Flip/flop of finite joins and finite meets of lattices

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, function-and-relation-composition

Let $\mathfrak{A}$, $\mathfrak{B}$, $\mathfrak{C}$ be lattices (in fact in the example I have in mind, they are distributive and even co-Heyting lattices). Let maps $f:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}$ and $g:\mathfrak{B}\rightarrow\mathfrak{C}$.

Let also $f$ preserve finite (including nullary) joins and $g$ preserve finite (including nullary) meets.

What can be said about the composition $g\circ f$? Specifically, is every map $z:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{C}$ representable as a composition $g\circ f$? If not, what are the necessary/sufficient conditions on $z$ to be representable in this way?

Comment: $g\circ f$ is monotone. What else may we know about it?